# Could not resolve archetype org.apache.maven.archetype Webapp

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, java-ee-6

I have some trouble creating a Marven project on Eclipse Kepler. I tried everything, from adding the remote catalog to the user setting xml file and could not find the solution on internet.

Do you guys have any idea?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Kepler? Really? This is more than 7 years old.

Comment: How are you going about it?

Comment: Well,my laptop just had 7 years in February, I changed my overload SSD, installed a new one and installed the latest Eclipse version (06-2020). It works now!